# How to increase the duration of Smooth View?

Tags: scripting, 3d-view, customization

Does anyone know how I can go about increasing the duration of the Smooth View setting beyond the maximum value of 1000?  It would be really useful for screen capture animations navigating between different cameras.

I found this operator:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.view2d.html#bpy.ops.view2d.smoothview

But I'm not sure how to change it...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: smooth view setting]